# Search bar gets cut off when using UISearchController with a UITabBarController inside a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have an application that has a `UITabBarController` in a `UINavigationController`. (The `UITabBarController` is not the "Initial View Controller" for the story board.)

In the initial `UIViewController`, I have a `UISearchController` which allows for content to be searched from a remote source.

This worked fine until I added the `UITabBarController`. Now, the search bar displays fine in the default state, but once you start typing inside of it, it gets pushed up past the top edge of the view.

I realize this probably has a lot to do with `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`, `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars`, and/or `edgesForExtendedLayout`, but in all my tweaking, I've been unable to find the magic combo to get the `UISearchController` to not push itself up past the top of the view.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

See these screengrabs from [this example project](https://github.com/albertbori/TabAndSearchTest):

**Initial view:**

[image: Initial view]

**Search text box becomes first responder:**

[image: Search textbox becomes first responder]

**After typing a word and hitting enter:**

[image]

Comment: example project working perfectly on iphone5S, ios8.0..no searchbar hide problem

Comment: Ah, might be a bug then. I'm seeing the error using the simulator for iPhone 6, iOS 8.3. I'm sure there has to be a way to work around it, though...

Comment: iphone 4s (not simulator): i see the problem. I am going mad for this bug

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too, and here's a solution: setting `definesPresentationContext = true` on `UITabBarController` instead of the table view controller seems to fix it.

Apparently, you have to go all the way up until navigation controller in container hierarchy. Not the most obvious thing in the world if you ask me.

Comment: what do you mean by going all the way up?

Comment: @malhal Checking your parentViewController, then the parent's own parentViewController, and so on - until you find a navigation controller.

Comment: Checking it for what? Do you mean put defines context yes in each controller until it fixes it?

Comment: By the way in my case i had a view controller in a tab controller, then all that inside a nav controller. It doesn't get past the tab controller. In that case the solution was to present the search manually from the right place.

Comment: @malhal If I remember this correctly, the alleged solution is to set `definesPresentationContext = true` on the immediate child of navigation controller. E.g., in the case of the question, that would be the tab bar controller.

Comment: Hi Nicky, although that works for normal view controllers not for the tab controller, something to do with it restricting access to the navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

Although `definesPresentationContext` worked for me previously, since iOS 10 at some point I had to disable Adjust Scroll View Insets on my search results view controller. More on my answer at [UISearchBar gets cut off when using a UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170729/uisearchbar-gets-cut-off-when-using-a-uinavigationcontroller-inside-a-uitabbarco/41799737#41799737)